# Remove text:u from strings in python

Tags: python, excel, string, parsing, document

I am using xlrd library to import values from excel file to python list.
I have a single column in excel file and extracting data row wise.
But the problem is the data i am getting in list is as

```
list = ["text:u'__string__'","text:u'__string__'",.....so on]
```

How can i remove this text:u from this to get natural list with strings ?

code here using python2.7

```
book = open_workbook("blabla.xlsx")
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
documents = []

for row in range(1, 50): #start from 1, to leave out row 0
    documents.append(sheet.cell(row, 0)) #extract from first col

data = [str(r) for r in documents]
print data
```

Comment: Without any knowledge of cord I'm sure `str(...)` is not the cause of your trouble and there should be an other way to access the content.

Comment: I have tried using  `data = [item.encode('utf-8') for item in documents]` instead of str line for converting list to unicode, but it give error `Cell object has no attribute encode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over items and remove extra characters from each word:

```
s=[]   
for x in list:
    s.append(x[7:-1]) # Slice from index 7 till lastindex - 1
```

Comment: This worked, but there are redundant `' ` at the end of each string in list

Answer (score 0):

If that's the standard input list you have, you can do it with simple `split`

```
[s.split("'")[1] for s in list]

# if your string itself has got "'" in between, using regex is always safe
import re
[re.findall(r"u'(.*)'", s)[0] for s in list]

#Output
#['__string__', '__string__']
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Following code helped me.

```
list = ["text:u'__string__'","text:u'__string__'",.....so on]
for index, item in enumerate(list):
      list[index] = list[index][7:] #Deletes first 7 xharacters
      list[index] = list[index][:-1] #Deletes last character
```